# VS Code Remote Debugger Fails to run on RPi 4

Tags: python

I reimaged my RPi4 to a fresh copy of Raspbian (V10, "buster").  After doing that I lost my SSH connection for remote debugging in VS Code (in Windows 10).  I was able to get the SSH back up and running, but when I run the debugger it crashes and the end of the traceback gives me this message.

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/**ctypes**/**init**.py", line 374, in **getitem**
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /bin/python3: undefined symbol: AttachDebuggerTracing

I have searched for this undefined symbol error but have not been able to find any information on what might be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up to Radmanz answer. No need to change the "program" setting, it is adding the "env" settings that is important

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env":{
                "PYDEVD_LOAD_NATIVE_LIB": "0",
                "PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON":"0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Back up and running in the debugger!

Comment: Can also confirm that this worked on Windows using Python 3.5.2 using version 1.56.2 of VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following env object to your launch.json

Given its an ARM processor, this will disable the use of any compiled code

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "__init__.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env":{
            "PYDEVD_LOAD_NATIVE_LIB": "0",
            "PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON":"0"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue on two different computers that debugging fine one day and then not starting the next. I have been searching all day for answers on the web and so far found nothing useful.

Comment: Please update the question or add a comment instead of an answer to communicate with the community.

Answer (score 0):

I use with odoo for debug and in my case must only add the env lines.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Odoo",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/odoo/odoo-bin",
        "args": [
            "-c",
            "${workspaceFolder}/config/odoo-server.conf",
            "-u",
            "module_to_update"
        ],
        "env":{
            "PYDEVD_LOAD_NATIVE_LIB": "0",
            "PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON":"0"
        }
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this error when trying to debug a remote container after my m1 MBP upgraded to Big Sur 11.4.

After adding the above (@Ivanda Nothabeer) env config, the issue was resolved:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_LOAD_NATIVE_LIB": "0",
                "PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON": "0",
            },
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using pytest-django and would like to access the debugger from python test explorer then you would also need to add the following to your .vscode/settings.json file:

```
{
    "python.envFile": "pytest.ini"
}
```

and finally add this to your pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
env = 
    PYDEVD_LOAD_NATIVE_LIB=False
    PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=False
```

This is more of a work around than a permanent solution. But I needed to get this working.